# Can't connect to local MySQL database using Crystal Reports

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports, odbc, connection-string

I'm trying to create a report using Crystal Reports and that first requires connecting to my local MySQL Database.

[image]

I'm using this database connector string:

```
Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3.6 Driver};Server=localhost:3306;Database=mcs;User=admin;Password=admin123;Option=3
```

I get this error:

[image]

The connector is installed and the MySQL database is there.

Answer (score 0):

- start >> search microsoft odbc administrator
- on user dsn click add >> search mysql odbc (if not found close >> right click on microsoft odbc administrator >> properties >> set target to "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe")
- set data source name=localhost >> tcp/ip=127.0.0.1 >> port=3306 >> user=admin >> password=admin123
- click test >> select database=mcs >> ok
- open database expert on crystal report >> make new connection >> odbc
- check select data source >> choose your data source name >> finish